# TypeScript output file doesn't get updated after transpilation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, transpiler

I downloaded [this seed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ts-starter-kit) for an Angular & TypeScript project. I updated the ts files and then transpiled it with no errors, but the output file doesn't get updated.

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
         "outFile": "dist/app.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [        
        "app/initialize.ts",
        "app/welcome/welcome.ts"
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Are you running it live or are you building it? If you're running it live it's normal, since it just stores the file in memory

Comment: @Corrado I don't understand your question. I run the TypeScript compiler via WebStorm. What should I do?

Comment: If you rename your previously exported file to something different and try to transpile new one, create it new file with previous name newly? If no (and I think that no) your project or any other internal file (like lib.d.ts) contains error or you have just broken transpiler. IDEs usually could not parse this kind of errors. Similar issue is for Visual Studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005390/visual-studio-typescript-compile-on-save-fails-project-contained-errors-but-n/42011418#42011418 see second part where are described how to run transpiler handly and see raw transpiler output.